# Cost vs. Costs when to use

Tags: grammaticality

When do we use cost and costs in a sentence? Like for instance in this sentence.. "Secrets have their costs or secrets have their cost?"

Comment: This is another 'count or non-count usage' question; 'cost' may be used either way, as [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cost_1) shows. You could investigate the relative frequencies of use of "secrets have their cost" and "secrets have their costs", using Google Ngrams. [originally posted 24 hours before this time:]

Comment: ... which will get you nowhere. Ngrams for "have their cost/s" are too likely to show false positives (eg "have their costs refunded"). You could compare with "take their toll/s", which will probably have fewer false positives, but isn't exactly equivalent. Raw Google searches show the ratio of examples of "secrets have their cost" : "secrets have their costs" to be 7 : 3 (uncancelled, and omitting the uses here). More results are needed. Essentially, either is acceptable: you can choose whether to stress the overall problem with having secrets, or the fact that there are various problems. 24+

Answer (score 4):

This is a question of whether you are talking about the notional or monetary price of secrets.

> **Cost** *noun*
>   1 An amount that has to be paid or spent to buy or obtain something:
>   *we are able to cover the cost of the event health-care costs*
>   [mass noun]: *the tunnel has been built at no cost to the state*
>   1.1 The effort, loss, or sacrifice necessary to achieve or obtain something:
>   *the government succeeded in diverting resources away from consumption at considerable cost to its political popularity*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cost)

Your example is closest to the dictionary's example in definition 1.1, and that would be how the phrase *secrets have their cost* would normally be understood. Some may prefer *the price of secrets*. This idiomatically refers to intangibles such as loss of trust or the psychological burden of not sharing a secret with people affected by the secret. The phrase could also be uttered when the secret becomes known and problems result which could have been prevented by more transparency at an earlier time. Compare this with *secrets take their toll* and *secrets extract a cost* - both of these forms aren't idiomatic with *tolls* and *costs*.

Nevertheless, the plural form *secrets have their costs* is also grammatical. When referring to definition 1, it is a more pragmatic statement about costs that may be incurred, for example, for security measures. As Edwin Ashworth and Egox point out, it can also refer to definition 1.1 if several types of 'costs' are considered.

Comment: The plural usage is not restricted solely to monetary costs. "Such solutions always have their costs, in money and in time" [Low Dose Exposures in the Environment: Dose-Effect ...
https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=3540210830
Christian Streffer, ‎H. Bolt, ‎D. Follesdal ] //  "These methods have their costs, particularly in terms of drop-out and failure" [Teaching Large Classes in Higher Education: How to ...
https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=1135350493
Gibbs, Graham, ‎Jenkins, Alan ] // "they also have their costs in the most precious of commodities, human suffering" [David Salsburg]...

Comment: Even so, a mass reference to the "cost", as Edwin says in a comment to the OP, stressing "the overall problem with having secrets" is a distinct choice, and should not be confused with "costs" ability to stress that "there are various problems" or to emphasize that more than one person will "pay the cost".